# How to achieve sudo su - root and run all command in ansible

Tags: ansible

We are not able to switch the ansible playbook connection to root id. eg. "sudo su -" and then execute the privilege commands. Kindly check and advice on correct approach. It works correctly using raw module but fails in a playbook

The below mention command is working fine with command prompt... How to configure the same via playbook.

```
ansible 13.127.x.x -e "ansible_user=ec2-user" --private-key ~/Downloads/test.pem  -m shell -a "sudo su - root ; cd /data/xyz/ ; ./start-xyz.sh"   -vvvv
```

Playbook Sample

```
  - name: Start 18 Service
    shell: sudo su - root ; cd /data/xyz/ ; ./xyz.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **become_user** to run script as another user, also shell use **chdir** support change folder

such as:

```
  - name: Start 18 Service
    hosts: yourhost
    become: true
    become_user: root 
    shell: "./xyz.sh"
    args:
      chdir: /data/xyz/
```